# HSP/HFP not working

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluez

I´m trying to use my bluetooth headset on my laptop on arch. I got it connected and am able to listen to music using A2DP. But trying to use it as a headset I don´t get any input nor output working when switching to HSP/HFP in pavucontrol.

```
pacmd list-cards
```

among others gives:

```
index: 3
name: <bluez_card.00_12_3D_00_31_E1>
driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
owner module: 30
properties:
    device.description = "BH-M20"
    device.string = "00:12:3D:00:31:E1"
    device.api = "bluez"
    device.class = "sound"
    device.bus = "bluetooth"
    device.form_factor = "headset"
    bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_12_3D_00_31_E1"
    bluez.class = "0x240404"
    bluez.alias = "BH-M20"
    device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
    device.intended_roles = "phone"
profiles:
    headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: unknown)
    a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP-Ziel) (priority 40, available: yes)
    off: Aus (priority 0, available: yes)
active profile: <a2dp_sink>
sinks:
    bluez_sink.00_12_3D_00_31_E1.a2dp_sink/#17: BH-M20
sources:
    bluez_sink.00_12_3D_00_31_E1.a2dp_sink.monitor/#25: Monitor of BH-M20
ports:
    headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:

    headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
```

This makes the headset practically useless to me.

Comment: I just posted a similar question and answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595301/hsp-hfp-setting-doesnt-work-with-plugable-bluetooth-adapter). It might work for you if your bluetooth adapter has a Broadcom BCM20702 chipset.